# UITextView and Class Sized Storyboard: Does not resize based on size of phone screen

Tags: ios, swift, textview

My TextView is in a ViewController that is embedded in a Navigation Controller. The problem is that, as you can see from the screenshot below, the text does not wrap based on the screen size, it's continuing off the screen. Class sizing is enabled and I'd rather not have to disable it if at all possible.

[image: Example]

Someone please help me out here. Also, I am only familiar with Swift.

Comment: are you using Aulolayout?

Comment: What do you mean by Autolayout? I have class sizing enabled.

Comment: There is no information about this out there, no research can be done. This is new. Seriously, who clicked the down arrow??

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the storyboard to make your user interface. In that case this might help.

1: Open your storyboard file.

2: Navigate to the screen which has the problem.

3: Make sure wAny hAny is displayed at the bottom os the screen. This ensures you are making the change to all size classes.

4: Click on you UITextView and using the left panel navigate to where you can view the constraints (this will be under the second tab from the right).

5: Check that the Trailing Space to: Superview and Leading Space to: Superview constraints are present. If so, check the values to make sure they are above -16 (if the values are below -16 the UITextView will be drawn outside of the screen). If not, add the Trailing Space to: Superview and Leading Space to: Superview constraints (for your purpose try values between -16 and 0).

6: Make sure there are no unwanted constraints.

If you are coding the constraints make sure the constraints are as I have described.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It definitely says wAny hAny at the bottom of the screen. Not sure where you are referring to in the left panel, but if I click on the TextView, in the right panel under the size inspector, I see a paragraph at the bottom under constraints that says: The selected views have no constraints. At build time, explicit left, top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view.

Comment: Hey your answer came close to the fix, I kept looking around and when I selected the UITextView and looked down at the bottom of the screen on the right, I clicked the second to right icon by the view items (buttons and tableviews, etc).  It had an option that said "add missing constraints" and when I clicked that it fixed it.